# Remotely accessing Weblogic server

Tags: java, weblogic

I installed locally and now running Weblogic Server in my machine. I can access the web application from my machine by using URL like 192.168.XXX.XXX:7001/myapp/, but I cannot access it from a different machine connected in same network. I have done this one: went to Administrative console, clicked on my server  and inserted my IP in the textbox beside Listen Address.But it didn't help.

Please, help me on this matter.

Answer (score 20):

The 'Listen Address' configuration item specifies which IP address your server listens on.

If it's set to 127.0.0.1 or localhost, then your server only listens on localhost address, which means it only serves requests come from localhost.

You should set it to the public IP address of your machine. Or simply set to 0.0.0.0, which means listen on all available address that your machine has.

Comment: Note: Look for this in the config.xml file in your domain folder.

Comment: Where exactly on the config.xml file I need to add my server's IP address?

Comment: It should be under tag <server>. Above <listen-address>.

Answer (score 5):

Companies block some ports due to security reason. And 7001 is one of those common ports which they block.
So you can perform following steps.

1. Type following command in cmd:
   telnet HOST.IP.ADDRESS PORT

   Ex: telnet 192.658.152.45 7001

   In case if it shows connecting and then stops, that means that port has been
   blocked.
   Try some other port , let say 8080.
2. If it works then change the default port in weblogic 
   Go to config.xml file in 
   \user_projects\domains\\config
3. Add listener port as

   `<server>
     <name>AdminServer</name>
     <listen-port>8080</listen-port>
     <listen-port-enabled>true</listen-port-enabled>
     <listen-address></listen-address>
   </server>`

Comment: This line works for me - <listen-address></listen-address>

Comment: This line works for me too - <listen-address></listen-address>

Answer (score 1):

**I had the same problem and solved it like:**

1. From the administration console change Listen address from **localhost** to admin server's IP
2. Stop Windows Firewall (I try only to define a new Rule to open port 7001 but without a result)

After that all works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Is your machine connected to the network?
2. Do you have any firewall installed? Is it blocking access from the outside?
3. Do you have any other software on your computer that is blocking access?
4. Does you network have hardware/software that blocks access to certain ports?
5. Other

Answer (score 0):

This is a firewall issue. You can add port 7001 an exception to the firewall or before that to confirm whether the issue is because of firewall, try

```
systemctl stop firewalld
```

Check again if you are able to access the console from a different machine.

Answer (score 0):

just allow specific port in firewall, Try this

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=7001/tcp
sudo firewall-cmd –-reload
```